# Is there PostgreSQL equivalent for SQL Server's timestamp column type?

Tags: postgresql, migration

For example I have in SQL Server this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Tender (
        Uid uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        Title nvarchar(2000) NULL,
        [Timestamp] timestamp NOT NULL
)
```

and I want to migrate to PostgreSQL 14.1. Timestamp is used for solving optimistic concurrency problem.

Is there alternative PostgresSQL DDL for [Timestamp] column?

Comment: FYI, `timestamp` is a deprecated synonym of `rowversion`. You should really be referencing it by it's less ambiguous/confusing name.

Comment: You can not assume that people that know Postgres know all exotic features of SQL Server. Please explain what you use the rowversion for. What problems does it solve?

Comment: Just create a `version` column in the table and problem solved. Optimistic locking implementation details are quite standard.